# Product variations getting same name as product

Tags: commerce

I did google this and found the following:

https://drupal.org/node/2146759

however, I cannot seem to find the fields they are indicating. Maybe I have the wrong version of commerce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I guess I was unfamiliar with the terminology. Here is what I did to find this, in case it helps anyone else. First go to Structure (which because I have the kickstart installed is actually in Site Settings under the Advanced column) then go to content types. Find the product type you want to edit, go to manage fields, edit the product variations and down the page a bit is a checkbox called "Auto generate the product title".